# Need elasticsearch query to fetch data based on some condition which has around 10K values check for particular column

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra

Need to write a cassandra or elasticsearch query which is equivalent to SQL "in" condition query.

In the "in" condition there are around 10K values to be matched.

Please suggest some good approach for this.

I tried with elasticsearh filters for some data. But I think it is not a good solution

Comment: Why do you think it's not a good solution? Also you should maybe explain your use case in a bit more details... maybe with some examples

Comment: I want to know/explore what are other options to do this. & I don't think about any approach for this solution for cassandra.

Comment: There are other options, but you need to show some concrete example of what you're trying to achieve.